# Designing a pcb without components, only copper pads and copper tracks connecting each pad to pad

Tags: pcb-design

I want to make a pcb a bit like this one.
[image: CTTO]

PLease guide me on how to design this kind of pcb, i plan on etching in on a rigid pcb board. 
I find it hard because in CAD there are no pads or lines you can add easily to your design because components are needed first in schematics to proceed in pcb design.

Comment: You can create a component that consists of a single pad.

Comment: There exist programs that allow you to make a PCB design without schematics, and that allow to add pads, traces and any copper area shape. DesignSpark PCB is such an example

Comment: also, please don't waste your time trying to etch this yourself, if that's what you were implying. You can buy professional quality 2 layer rigid PCB's nowadays for $2/10 boards

Answer (score 4):

This is very clearly a case for a classical schematic capture program.

You'd simply start out by defining your "pad arrays" as connector footprints (which they are!), then connect the right things in the schematic – and then route the board.

The schematic part is important! It allows you to check whether you've done everything right by abstracting "this needs to be connected to that" from the route the trace needs to take to achieve that. Trying to directly route the board without having defined beforehand what connects to which in a schematic is horrendously error prone – and atop of that, very slow:

when you've made a schematic, your program will highlight the pad you want to connect to, which makes it much much easier and faster to route things. Also, routing helpers are available in many programs – from simple "push and shove a bit" routers to full autorouter.

So, learn yourself a little more about board design CAD tools. I'd recommend [KiCAD](https://www.kicad.org/). It's easy to design your footprints in it, use them in a board and layout that board, and export it for production.

Comment: I am having trouble finding the right pads from library so I resorted to make my own but I am finding it very hard to cope with the mils imperial units, I am so used to using millimeter. I have research a bit and found out that even though I am using no components i can still follow the SCHEMATIC to BOARD routing style. Thanks so much! is KiCAD free by the way? Thanks again!

Comment: you can switch the units with a single click

Comment: yes, it's free as in beer and as in speech.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways. (1) you can create your own "components" as new parts and with their own footprints and then assemble everything in the PCB layout. (2) you can create manually the pcb layout with the copper traces, it is not that difficult. In Eagle for example, you cn do it with the pad tool.

Comment: I started creating my own footprints, but got stuck with measurements because eagle uses mils unit and i am used to mm, i just need to measure the actual size of the pads that i'm making a pcb for but I cannot because the pads are really really tiny and I only have a ruler, I am going to buy accurate digital caliper. Thanks for advice on how to tackle this! I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw something by hand a PCB gerber editor program will work, you'll need to keep track of the files and how they connect to other layers and won't have a good DFM (Design for Manufacture, which checks to make sure the PCB house can manufacture the PCB and checks clearances).

It would be best to use a free program, the schematic will be pretty simple and you'll have DFM.

I would recommend eagle or ki cad.

Aslo PCBway is my manufacturer for most boards, and they do flat flex (for really cheap now)

Comment: I want to learn cad as I am an electronics engineering students, i am a shame as I find it hard to do these simple things. thanks for recommendation of DFM and pcbway. alsoo may i ask if eagle has feature or something that checks if your rounting is shorted? Thanks for noticing my post! I appreciate your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a contrarian view to the "need to have a schematic" notion.

The purpose of the schematic is to create the netlist.  In fact in the old days (before CAE tools) of hand drawn schematics we sometimes, depending on how the board was going to be implemented, would created the net list by hand.

For something like you're describing, you could do that with a spreadsheet.  Then you would need a geometry document or file that describes physically where the components & pins you reference in your hand created net list are located.

A good schematic capture & layout tool does all of this for you, more or less automatically.  But that's not the same as saying the schematic route is absolutely necessary for the simple design you have presented.